# (не)дорогих - слитно/раздельно

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Увидел в [новостях](http://www.gazeta.ru/business/news/2015/12/24/n_8053277.shtml) такой абзац:

> «Сегодня необоснованное, прямо скажем, спекулятивное повышение
>   стоимости продуктов, товаров, услуг приводит к снижению жизненного
>   уровня людей.
>
> Нужно использовать все имеющиеся рыночные инструменты
>   для сдерживания роста цен, расширить долю **не дорогих, но качественных**
>   отечественных товаров», — заявил президент.

Правильно я понимаю, что тут ошибка? Ведь в предложении нет противопоставления *дорогих - качественных* и словосочетание **не дорогих* можно заменить на *доступных*, имея ввиду следующую мысль:

> ...расширить долю доступных, но при этом качественных товаров...

Answer (score 2):

Да, здесь ошибка. Грамматически возможный вариант: "не дорогих, а дешёвых". Здесь можно: "недорогих и при этом высококачественных", "недорогих, но хороших". Ваш вариант тоже возможен (я лично не использую слово "качественный" в этом значении).